# get words out instead of substrings

Tags: python, function, substring, words

I want to search a a file with sentences, and get the sentences with certain words out. I wrote this code to do that.

```
def finding(q):
    for item in sentences:
        if item.lower().find(q.lower()) != -1:
            list.append(item)

        for sentence in list:
            outfile.write(sentence+'\r\n')

finding('apple')
finding('banana')
```

The problem is that this finds substrings instead of words. So for example the sentence'the appletree is big'. Would also get extracted.

Comment: The code `item.lower().find(q.lower()) != -1` is better spelt `q.lower() in item.lower()`

Comment: Don't use the name `list`; this masks the built-in type. Use `found` or something similarly descriptive.

Comment: Watch out - you don't initialize `list` in the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the line into words; the simplest is to use `str.split()`:

```
for line in sentences:
    if any(q.lower() == word.lower() for word in line.split()):
        outfile.write(line + '\n')
```

You can add a `.strip('?!."()')` to remove most common punctuation as well, perhaps.

Note that Python files, opened in text mode, will already use `\r\n` on Windows if you write out a `\n`.  The code above also *directly* writes the matched lines to the output file.

Alternatively, use a regular expression to find matches:

```
import re

def finding(q, sentences, outfile):
    pattern = re.compile(r'\b{}\b'.format(re.escape(q), flags=re.IGNORE)
    for line in sentences:
        if pattern.match(line)
            outfile.write(line + '\n')
```

`re.IGNORE` makes the match ignore case, `\b` adds word boundaries and `re.escape()` removes any expression metacharacters from the input query.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative:

```
sentences = [
    'this has a banana',
    'this one does not',
    'bananatree should not be here',
    'go go banana go'
]

import re
found = filter(re.compile(r'\bbanana\b', flags=re.I).search, sentences)
# ['this has a banana', 'go go banana go']
```